# Running SSRS Query gives blank results

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

When I run this Query in SSRS the table does not fill out. There should be about 200 rows but all I get is this:

[image: table with one blank row]

Here is the Query:

```html
SELECT
    tblDataPermit.ApplicationNumber
   ,tblDataParcel.StreetNum
   ,tblDataParcel.StreetName
   ,tblDataPermit.Applicant
   ,tblDataPermit.Status
   ,tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="Text4Size10"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Cycle
   ,tblDataPermit.ApplicantPhone AS BusPhone
   ,tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="Text2Size50"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ContactName,
   ,tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="Text1Size10"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ConPhone
   ,tblDataPermit.ApplicationType AS Grp,
   ,tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="ExtraYesNo1"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS A
   ,tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="ExtraYesNo2"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS E
   ,tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="ExtraYesNo3"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS F
   ,tblDataPermit.XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="YesNo3"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS S
   ,ExpirationDates.ExpirationDate AS Due
   ,IStatuss.Status AS ADate
   ,MaxCompletionDates.MaxCompletionDate
   ,SysCod.CodRcdTyp
   ,SysCod.CodLabel
   ,SysCod.CodOrder
FROM
   SysCod

INNER JOIN tblDataPermit
    ON SysCod.CodOrder = tblDataPermit.Type

INNER JOIN tblDataParcel ON tblDataPermit.ParcelID = tblDataParcel.ParcelID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT ProjectNumber, ExpirationDate FROM tblDataPermit AS tblDataPermit_2 WHERE (Type = '54')) AS ExpirationDates ON tblDataPermit.ApplicationNumber = ExpirationDates.ProjectNumber 

INNER JOIN
(SELECT ProjectNumber, Status FROM tblDataPermit AS tblDataPermit_3 WHERE (Type = '54')) AS IStatuss ON tblDataPermit.ProjectNumber = IStatuss.ProjectNumber 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(tblDataActions.CompletionDate) AS MaxCompletionDate, tblDataPermit_1.Type, tblDataPermit_1.ProjectNumber

FROM tblDataActions INNER JOIN tblDataPermit AS tblDataPermit_1 ON tblDataActions.ApplicationNumber = tblDataPermit_1.ApplicationNumber

GROUP BY tblDataPermit_1.Type, tblDataPermit_1.ProjectNumber
HAVING (tblDataPermit_1.Type = '54')) AS MaxCompletionDates ON tblDataPermit.ApplicationNumber = MaxCompletionDates.ProjectNumber

WHERE (tblDataPermit.Type = '72') 
AND CodLabel IN (@AppStatus) 
AND XmlDataField.value('(//*[local-name()="Text4Size10"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') IN (@Cycle)
```

Here is the report data:
[image: report data]

[image: AppStatusDataSet]

[image: ActionStatusDataSet]

The main tables are tblDataPermit and tblDataActions. These tables get the actual labels for Type and Status from the table SysCod. Here are exaples of each table:

[image: tblDataPermit]

[image: tblDataActions]

[image: SysCod]

Comment: Kinda hard to troubleshoot when there isn't any sample data in a copy/paste format. However, from the screenshots you supplied, I can see that it wouldn't return anything  because you filter for `(tblDataPermit.Type = '72')`... The screenshot you posted has Type = `54`.

Comment: @BJones is almost certainly correct.  In one of the inner joins, you are specifying `WHERE Type = 54` but in the larger query, you are specifying `WHERE Type = 72`.  You likely won't get any results that have both types.

Comment: I apologize that this Sql Database is somewhat complex.

Comment: The Type 72 refers to the application type that contains property information (address, etc) and Type 54 is the application that contains inspection results. I think the issue may be in pulling the labels from SyCod for Application Status and Action Status. The info comes from the same columns (Label and CodOrder) but are differentiated by the CodRecType Column. Application Status comes from the CodRecType PMTMAS and Action Status comes from the CodRecTyp MGMAST. You can see this in their data sets.

Comment: Not sure how to copy/paste sample data with the column headers. Small examples are shown in the last the table images I posted earlier.

Comment: First thing to do is to run the query form the query designer with SSRS (right-click dataset and choose query). If you dont; get any results there then obviously the problem is with the query and/or the datasource it's pointing at. If you get expected results then look if there are any filters applied to the table or dataset. Also, assuming dataset checks out OK, create a new report, copy the dataset and then add a simple table and see if you can reproduce.